# What is animation duration for android status bar

Tags: android, animation

What is the slide_in, slide_out duration of status bar animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should rely on an exact time because it might differ in future versions of Android or due to modifications from manufacturers and carriers.
Also there's no documented API to retrieve this time so you'd have to hardcode it which seems a bad idea due to the above reasons.

Comment: Although it is true that it can cause problems to use a hard-coded animation duration, it does not answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

For Lollipop (and presumable older versions as well) the visibility animations for status bar and navigation bar on phones are resolved in `com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager#selectAnimationLw` which selects the required XML animation resources, based on the bar type and it's current state, e.g. `R.anim.dock_top_exit` for *hiding* the *status bar*.

The status bar animations are quite simple, defining

- a **duration of 250 milliseconds** for both hiding and showing
- a **start delay of 100 milliseconds** for the hiding animation
- a cubic `AccelerateInterpolator` (with factor 1.5) for hiding, and a cubic `DecelerateInterpolator` (factor 1.5 as well) for showing.

As @florian-h mentioned, if you rely on those values you should be aware that not only different versions of Android handle showing and hiding in a different manner, but also that some device configurations (e.g. car screens, televisions) may not have those bars displayed at all.

Side note: I have extracted the values from the official Android OS sources that can be obtained from http://source.android.com.